# jscript how to find current url and redirect + QueryString

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reload the same page with new parameter for example.

www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx to redirect to www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx?querystring=helloworld.

What I really need to do is redirect to `www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx` to redirect to `www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx?Myparam=yellow` and i dont want to hardcode `www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will redirect
www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx to www.mysite.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx?Myparam=yellow

```
location.href=location.href + '?MyParam=yellow'
```

You can do also:

```
if (location.href=='http://www.example.com/hi/hi/yo/default.aspx')
    location.href=location.href + '?MyParam=yellow'
```

Comment: That sort of works, but it doesnt get the current parameters, so i have ?myparam1=hello&myparam2=yo&myparam3=yellow

Comment: What is the current parameters?. Please explain